# Problem unit testing silverlight project with dynamically downloaded xaps

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mef

We have a Loader project and a Core project. The core project is what contains all our views and view models we need to unit test.When testing the view models we want to run the loader like it would normally so it correctly sets up any required services. To do this we thought we could create a test bootstrapper that inherits from the Loader projects bootstrapper. This will enable our navigation service and IOC container so we can then test the view models.

The problem we found though is because we are inheriting from the loader bootstrapper and will be calling the view models directly in our unit tests we need a project reference to both the loader and the core. This adds the Loader.dll and Core.dll to the Test Projects xap file.

when we kick of the TestBootstrapper that inherites from Loader.Bootstrapper, the Loader project downloads the core.xap and imports the core.bootstrapper to initialise it. however by doing this when mef tries to import the core.bootstraper it is matching it with the core.xap that the loader downloads and the testproject.xap that has a a reference to the core project. This causes the import to fail because it has already been initialised.

Is there a way we can still dynamically download the xaps but won't cause issue with cross referencing between projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Copy Local` to `False` on the reference should ensure that MEF doesn't try to load it twice.

I think it's good that you're testing the dynamic XAP loading, however I think you'll run into further issues as you continue to test.  I would highly suggest testing your ViewModels without requiring to do the whole dynamic download of XAPs every time you need to run a test.  Each ViewModel should be able to be tested in isolation.  If this is a fairly small project, you probably won't feel too much pain.  Though once the project gets bigger the time it will take to dynamically download the XAPs will become bigger and the time it takes to run tests will grow longer and longer.  Anyway, just my suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunatly the project is already large which is causing some issues. The Core project which has all the ViewModels depends on services that are set up in the Loader Project. Also when i set the Copy Local to False on the Test Project i get this exception "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly "

Comment: Actually i got that working, i still needed the Copy Local = True for the Loader project just not the Core Project. The problem i now have is that the Styles are set up in the Loader App.xaml but this is bypassed to the Bootstrapper.

Comment: We sorted the resource issue out, we had to add references to the controls that the style was for to the test project.